# How can I parse data from server using Json?

Tags: php, android, json

This is my php file. I want to parse data in android as JSON object. Hw can i do this.

```
<?php
include("../include/connection.php");
    $old_pass="1234";
    $new_pass="123";
    $re_pass="123";
    $contact_no="8285663445";
     $chg_pwd="select * from users where contact_no='$contact_no'";
    $data=mysqli_query($conn,$chg_pwd) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $chg_pwd1=mysqli_fetch_array($data);
     $data_pwd=$chg_pwd1['password'];
    if($data_pwd==$old_pass){
    if($new_pass==$re_pass){
        $update_pwd="update users set password='$new_pass' where contact_no='$contact_no'";
        $updata=mysqli_query($conn,$update_pwd) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        $json = array("status" => 1, "msg" => "password reset successfully");
    }
    else{

        $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Your new and Retype Password is not match!");
    }
    }
    else
    {
    $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Request method not accepted");
    }
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

This is my android function where I am trying to get response from the server.

```
private void signupTrace(String response ) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(response);
    if(jsonObject.getString("status").equals("1")){
        Log.e("log", "" + response);
        String mesg= jsonObject.getString("msg");
        Log.e("msg",""+mesg);
        Toast.makeText(Change_Password.this,mesg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    else if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("0")){
        String mesg= jsonObject.getString("msg");
        Toast.makeText(Change_Password.this,mesg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), " Server failed", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Undo", null)
                .setActionTextColor(Color.RED)
                .show();
    }
}
```

And this is what I am getting in my logcat.

> 0-09 15:33:23.578 23721-25138/com.pickpamphlet.easydeals E/mapvalue {old_pass=12345, contact_no=8947897487, re_pass=zxcvbnm, new_pass=zxcvbnm}
>   10-09 15:33:24.813 23721-23721/com.pickpamphlet.easydeals E/log: {"status":0,"msg":"Request method not accepted"}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON parsing in Android code is done correctly.

1234 is not the password in the database. Please check if your condition is correct.

```
if($data_pwd==$old_pass){

}
else
{
    $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Request method not accepted");
}
```

Check your php condition properly and make sure the you are passing the correct values.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was in my php script.